# Picturbox not updating with image?

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

I'm building a win-forms UI application and here is my issue. I have a picturebox to which I assigne an image (through a command of an in-app button) but it doesn't update the picturebox with the image; it just stays blank. However if I click the "Go Back" button and then re-click the "Show Picture" button which is supposed to show the image on the picturebox, it does show it. Below are the steps followed in the code for each button:

First button: (Clicked after the picturebox supposedly shows the picture) ***Show Picture***

```
album.Location = new Point(67, 45);
        album.Size = new Size(590, 374);
        album.Visible = true;
        pictureBox10.Size = new Size(320, 180);
        pictureBox10.Location = new Point(135, 100);
        pictureBox10.Visible = true;


string PCname = Environment.UserName;
        string picturedir = some working path here
        int i = 0;
        if (File.Exists(picturedir + "\\" + i.ToString() + ".png") == true)
        {
            pictureBox10.Image = Image.FromFile(picturedir + "\\" + i.ToString() + ".png");

        }
```

Second Button (Clicked after the picturebox supposedly shows the picture) ***Go Back***

```
album.Location = new Point(185, 45);
        album.Size = new Size(450, 374);
        album.Visible = true;
        pictureBox10.Visible = false;
```

Notes: 
1) Of course, when the ***Go Back*** button is clicked, it brings up the ***Show Picture*** button for the user to click on it.
2) "album" is a panel which contains all of the rest mentioned buttons and picturebox10.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What does the debugger say? Note that pbox will only show a new image if you re-assign it, not when you change the image.

Comment: Though your question is a bit unclear. But I think you have to set your code into `form_load event`. To show it after loading the form.

Comment: Update: I assigned an image to the picturebox when the program is initialized (meaning that now it already is assigned to an image before the click of the "Show Picture" button), but it STILL does the same as before...

Comment: Have you solved your issue?